# Data storage in memory- Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to store this kind of information in memory all the time.

```
app_id    admin_id    url           status
123       1           xyz.com       1
123       2           xyz.com       0
539       3           exmaple.com   1
876       4           new.com       1
```

My main concern is that i want the lookup to be easy and fast. Like at any point to query :

1. get the `url` and `status` for a particular `admin_id`.
2. get all `admin_id` for a particular `app_id`.

SO how do i store this information in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something as follows. Create an object for each row. And keep the references in and array `byAdminId` for admin-id, and an object `byAppId` for app-id, the `add` function does that in following. `getByAppId` and `getByAdminId` functions for retrieval of those objects.

```
var store = (function() {
    var byAdminId = [];
    var byAppId = {};

    return {
        add: function(appId, adminId, url, status) {
            var d = {
                appId: appId,
                adminId: adminId,
                url: url,
                status: status
            };
            if (appId in byAppId) { // You could also use byAppId.hasOwnProperty(appId) here
                byAppId[appId].push(d);
            } else {
                byAppId[appId] = [];
                byAppId[appId].push(d);
            }
            byAdminId[adminId-1] = d;
        },
        getByAppId: function(appId) {
            if (appId in byAppId) {
                return byAppId[appId];
            }
            return null;
        },
        getByAdminId: function(adminId) {
            return byAdminId[adminId-1];
        }
    };
})();

store.add(123, 1, "abc.com", 1);
store.add(123, 9, "xyz.com", 0);
store.add(539, 3, "exmaple.com", 1);
store.add(876, 4, "new.com", 1);

var objs = store.getByAppId(123);
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    // access admin id as follows
    // objs[i].adminId
}

var obj = store.getByAdminId(1);
// access the url and status as follows
// obj.url
// obj.status
```

Comment: Thanks..i was also thinking on the same lines..major concern was the lockup to be fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your items in an array called `a`, you could use a couple of dictionaries:

```
var i;

var app_id_index = {};
var admin_id_index = {};
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    app_id_index[a[i].app_id] = a[i];
    admin_id_index[a[i].admin_id] = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/intro_dojo_store/

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data.html#dojo-data